# fetch count of employee based on category using join

Tags: postgresql, join

Below mentioned are 2 tables with category and employee information.

Table 1: Category

```
Code_Type  Code_Value  Code_Description
PT         1           Sales
PT         2           Marketing
PT         3           IT
PT         4           Software
PT         5           Hardware
PT         6           Non Technical
```

Table 2: Employee

```
Emp_id     Code_Type   Emp_Categ
E1<        PT          1
E2<        PT          6
E3<        PT          1
E4<        PT          3
E5<        PT          3
E6<        PT          5
E7<        PT          5
E8<        PT          5
E9<        PT          1
E10        PT          6
E11        PT          1
E12        PT          6
E13        PM          1
E14        PM          6
E15        PM          1
E16        PM          6
```

EXPECTED RESULT: total employee for category PT

```
Code_Value    Code_Description        Count
 PT           1    Sales              4
 PT           2    Marketing          0
 PT           3    IT                 2
 PT           4    Software           0
 PT           5    Hardware           3
 PT           6    Non Technical      3
```

OBTAINED RESULT: total employee for category PT

```
Code_Type    Code_Value  Code_Description      Count
PT           1           Sales                 4
PT           3           IT                    2
PT           5           Hardware              3
PT           6           Non Technical         3
```

QUERY USED:

```
select Code_Value,Code_Description,count(Emp_id)
from Category 
left join Employee on Code_Value = Emp_Categ
where Code_Type='PT'
GROUP BY Code_Value,Code_Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery like this:

`select 
     Code_Value,
     Code_Description, 
     (select count(Emp_id) from Category inner join Emp_Categ on Code_Value = Emp_Categ where Code_Type='PT') as count
from 
     Category 
where 
     Code_Type='PT'
group by Code_Value,Code_Description`

Comment: this query generates following error  -- subquery uses ungrouped column "code_value" from outer query